# Does Firefox have an equivalent of Chromes ability to quickly discover https mixed content?

Tags: firefox, https

I'm switching to Firefox from Chrome for webdev work.

Chrome's devtools allow developers to quickly discover mixed content in a site that uses https. In the 'security' tab the developer is shown that mixed content is a problem, invited to reload the page, and directed to look that network panel where a pre-written filter is employed.

Firefox devtools don't appear to have a 'security' tab.

Does Firefox devtool have any equivalent of the discovery process described above?

I've hunted through the tabs and settings within Firefox's devtools and having found any such equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

Yes, [Firefox is able](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) to detect and report content served over HTTP on a HTTPS website. It can report both:

- [mixed active content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Mixed_active_content), or content that has access to all or parts of the DOM of the page (think of `<script>`);
- [mixed passive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content#Mixed_passivedisplay_content), or content that cannot alter the page (think of `<img>`).

To see the reported content:

- open a new tab;
- enable the [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) or the [tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (with the Tools, you need to open the 'Console' tab);
- load your HTTPS website;
- mixed content will be reported in the console, like shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can already see the warnings. But I was trying to find out if firefox has an equivalent of Chromes capacity to quickly discover mixed content warnings while filtering out everything else.

Comment: You can achieve filtering, in this specific case, by adding "blocked loading mixed" in the filter in the console, above.